# How to display a scaled down html canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am doing an animation on a 1320px * 1440px html5 canvas. But I don't want to see this huge canvas on the screen rather I want to see this on a 550px * 600px canvas so that the drawing quality looks better. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are decreasing the height and width by a factor of 2.4, so you simply need to decrease the canvas and the animation inside it by that factor as well.

- Make the canvas width attribute = 550 and the height attribute = 600
- Multiply the animation width and height by .4167 (or 1/2.4) to scale it appropriately. You could easily do that by using the `context.scale(.4167, .4167);` method before drawing anything.

More information about `scale()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale).